# Jquery Datepicker prev, next icon hiding on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

I am using jquery date picker, on top of datepicker two icons is available(next, previous) when i hovering on those icons they are disappearing.

[image]

I have checked on hover two classes getting added in tag

classes - ui-state-hover ui-datepicker-next-hover

what can the problem be?

```
 <a class="ui-datepicker-prev ui-corner-all" data-handler="prev" data-event="click" title="Prev">
 <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w">Prev</span>
 </a>
```

On hover these two classes are getting added in anchor tag

```
 ui-state-hover ui-datepicker-prev-hover
```

Now I Want to remove above mentioned classes from anchor tag on hover/mouseover

ui-datepicker-prev ui-corner-all **ui-state-hover ui-datepicker-prev-hover**

Comment: Please provide working code.

Comment: What version of jQueryUI.js and jQueryUI.css? Are they the same?

Comment: both versions are different css-1.8.18, js- 1.9.2

Comment: @ankitapatel i have pasted the header code of datepicker

Comment: But this code is not helpful. Please provide working snippet code.

Comment: Start by using matching versions of js and css

Comment: @ankitapatel on mouse ove/hover two classes are getting added but i don want those two classes how can i prevent them from adding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this:

```js
$(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

```css
#ui-datepicker-div .ui-widget-header { 
 background: #2D8CB9; 
}
.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default{
  background: transparent!important;
}
.ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight{
  background: #fffa90!important;
}
.ui-datepicker-calendar th {
 color: #2D8CB9;
}
.ui-state-active, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-active, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-active, a.ui-button:active, .ui-button:active, .ui-button.ui-state-active:hover{
  color:#333!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working fine ..Some CSS was creating problem Btw Thanks for your efforts.